# Using find in terminal after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: terminal, command-line, catalina, iterm

After upgrading to Catalina, I am unable to use `find` command in iterm2. Here is the error:

```
--- ~ » sudo find / -iname mysqld.sock                                                                                                   
Password:
find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’: No such file or directory
```

I added iTerm2 and zsh to "Full Disk Access" group in "Security & Privacy", but this did not solve the problem.

What else should I do?

Comment: Are you using the BSD version of find that comes with the OS or the version that comes with findutils in Homebrew?